# Why does "grep -w" match words followed by hyphen/minus ("-")?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I need to ask you about using `grep` command in a Bash script in Debian.

I have got for example file with these lines:

```
/fruit-/apple.txt
/fruit-/banana.txt
/fruit-/samples
/vegetables-/carrot.txt
/vegetables-/garlic.txt
```

I want to select all lines where is word `fruit-`.

I can call command:

```
grep -w "fruit-" file.txt
```

Output will be:

```
/fruit-/apple.txt
/fruit-/banana.txt
/fruit-/samples
```

But when I use command:

```
grep -w "fruit" file.txt
```

I also get same output such as above. But it's wrong. Output should be 0. Because I don't type `-` in pattern.

Why doesn't `grep` treat the `-` correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-w` option indeed tells `grep` to only look for lines that match `fruit` as a "word", meaning that it must either start at the beginning of the line or be preceded by a "non-word" character, and either end at the end of the line or be followed by a "non-word" character.

However, a "word" character as per the man-page of `grep` is:

> Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

That means that the `-` is a "non-word" character, and `fruit-` will match the "word-search" for `fruit` as the matching algorithm will stop upon reaching the `-`.

Now, it seems you want to select only those lines where the content between the first two `/` *is exactly* `fruit`, as opposed to *containing the pattern* `fruit`. In these cases, you have to make the match more explicit:

- With `grep`, you can say:

  ```
  grep "^/fruit/" file.txt
  ```

  This will anchor the pattern to the beginning of the line and only accept those lines where there is no `-` after the `fruit`.
- Alternatively, use `awk` with the `/` set as field-separator:

  ```
  awk -F/ '!$1&&$2=="fruit"' file.txt
  ```

  This will only accept lines which have an empty first field (i.e. start right with a `/`) and whose second field is exactly `fruit`.

Answer (score 2):

[@AdminBee](/a/669095) has already clarified what a *word* meant for `grep`, I'll just add how you can tell it to use other definition of word in this context.

`grep -w word` is more or less looking for `word`s that are neither preceded nor followed by word characters.

Some `grep` implementations have a `-P` option to switch to perl-like regexps.

`perl` has explicit *look around* operators intended for checking whether something matches before or after.

`grep -w word` would be something `grep -P '(?<!\w)word(?!\w)'` where `(?<!pattern)` and `(?!pattern)` are respectively *negative look behind* and *ahead* operators.

If you want to consider that `-` is a word constituent, you can change it to:

```
grep -P '(?<![\w-])fruit(?![\w-])'
```

Which will match on `foo fruit bar` or `foo/fruit/bar` or `foo/fruit` but not on `foo/fruit-bar` as `fruit` is followed by a `-`.

Or for *any character but `/`*:

```
grep -P '(?<![^/])fruit(?![^/])'
```

Or for *whitespace delimited words*:

```
grep -P '(?<!\S)word(?!\S)'
```

(where `\S`, same as `[^\s]` similar to POSIX `[^[:space:]]` is any character not classified as whitespace).